# PHP - Laravel: Getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to save javascript code to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, permissions

I know that this is generally frowned upon, but for my specific reasons which I'll state below, I need this functionality:

So what we're doing on this website is that we are allowing users to buy "stores" on which they can sell products, and now those users want to add stuff like "Facebook Pixel" to their stores to allow them to track different activities.

Here's my form responsible for the code

```
    <form action="{{ url('vendor/store/settings/analytics/update') }}" method="POST" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="analytics-form">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 analytics-box">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Please pick a type of analytics to install:</label>
                <select name="analytic_type[]" id="" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($analytic_types as $type)
                       <option value="{{ $type }}">{{ ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $type)) }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="">Please type/paste the code for this analytic:</label>
                 <textarea class="form-control" cols="5" rows="5" name="analytic_code[]" required></textarea>
                 <br>
              </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="applyAnalytics" type="submit" {{ $store->vendor->hasAnalytics() ? '' : 'disabled'}}>Apply Changes</button>
    </form>
```

And here's the controller method I want to "hit":

```
public function updateAnalytics(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $store = auth()->user()->store;
            auth()->user()->analytics()->delete();
            if($request->has('analytic_type')) {
                foreach($request->analytic_type as $index => $value) {
                    Analytics::create([
                        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                        'analyticable_id' => $store->id,
                        'analyticable_type' => get_class($store),
                        'method_type' => $request->analytic_type[$index],
                        'method_code' => $request->analytic_code[$index],
                    ]);
                }
            }    
            flash(__("Common.Saved_Successfully"));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            session()->flash('title', __("Common.Error"));
            session()->flash('message', __("Common.An_Error_Happened"));
            session()->flash('message-class', "error");
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

This method works fine locally if I enter either normal text or code into the textarea, but if I tried to enter & submit the below block of code everything blows up, this block of code is the one provided by **Facebook Pixel** to its users, which I want to save in my database:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '339673053324500');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=339673053324500&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

If I put the above code into the text area and submit the data to the server, I get this error below:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /app/public/vendor/store/settings/analytics/update on this server.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The server isn't even allowing me to hit the route in question, or any other route from this form as long as I am submitting code.

**Note:**

This is probably not an actual permission issue but a security related thing, because I've tried changing permissions on the server for all of the involved files from 0644 to 0755 and nothing changed, of course I might have done something wrong along the way, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which part of your application really throws that error? Is there anything written to your server's error log, or to the application log?

Comment: @NicoHaase Nothing is getting produced neither in Laravel's log nor in cpanel's errors log.